An Extremely Simple Programming Language
After preparing for years, you go to the 51st Intergalactic Coding Olympiad. The moment the test starts, you flip over the question paper. To your surprise, it has only one question which involves... none of the programming languages that you studied.
The question describes a programming language called Easy, which can only do five things.

It can set a variable to 0, creating it if it doesn't exist.
It can increment a variable if the variable already exists.
It can create a (possibly infinite) loop containing any set of instructions. Loops can be nested.
It can break out of a loop if two specified variables are equal. When this type of statement is used nested loops, it only breaks the innermost loop.
It can return a variable and stop the program.

The syntax is very similar to Java syntax. Each one of the above instructions counts as 1 instruction.
Here's an example Easy program (with 7 instructions) that returns 1, illustrating the syntax:
i = 0;
j = 0;
i++;
loop {
    j++;
    if (i == j) break;
}
return j;

The question has three parts:

a) Write a program with at most 15 instructions that returns an integer greater than 20.

b) Write a program with at most 20 instructions that returns an integer greater than 1000.

c) Write a program with at most 25 instructions that returns an integer with a decimal representation that cannot fit in this universe.


Bonus: What is the largest number you can return on each part?
Note: The bonus question is well-defined and has a unique answer for each of the 3 cases (15, 20, 25 instructions).  For details, see answer by will.octagon.gibson.
Note: Since some tame-looking Easy programs can return HUGE numbers, Easy is not run by directly running the code, but rather by scanning the code with a superintelligent coding AI and making it compute the value that is returned by figuring out what each code segment does.

I’m voting to close this question because it is an open-ended puzzle. According to the question, answers are not expected to prove optimality, just to try to get a big number. This has a strong tendency to lead to an effectively infinite number of answers where people make incremental improvements without a clear endpoint.

Do you (the OP) know the answer (the largest score you can get)?

@bobble Would providing my answers make this any less open-ended?

@mathworker21 I don't have any sensible ways of proving optimality, but I've got some answers that are pretty big.

@mathlander Please read the post I linked in my first comment. The fundamental problem is with the question, and cannot be solved by any individual answer (unless that answer proves optimality). Open ended puzzles are problematic because "instead of a puzzle what we really have is a game: find the best thing you can come up with. "

Let me edit to try to fix this.

@bobble is this good now?

@mathlander in my opinion, it still is open-ended because people will, in practice, keep posting answers for a bonus question, so we get the same answer explosion. (And I suspect even if you just posted "write a program which returns more than X", no bonus question, people would still post extra answers whenever they improved on X.) However now, I think it shifts into a grey area so maybe other people will disagree.

I assume loops can be nested, and breaking out only exits the innermost loop?

Yes. I should clarify that.

Maybe Codegolf stackexchange will like this problem if Puzzling doesn't like it.

I was considering Codegolf but decided to post here first because I have more experience on this site.

Must variables be declared before they can be used? Or are they implicitly declared and set to zero on first use, and the explicit set-to-zero (e.g. j=0;) is only needed when forcing a variable back to zero?

They are automatically declared when first being set to 0.

That doesn't answer my question. If the first line of the program is i++; is the variable automatically declared and set equal to one, or does the Easy compiler cough up an error for not having first declared the variable?

A variable has to be declared before it is used.

Speaking of "simple" languages, if you haven't leared FRACTRAN, take a look at it.  It's mind-bending.

The loop itself counts as one instruction? So the sample code has 7 instructions, right?

@ilkkachu Yes, it has 7 instructions.

An interesting spinoff could be creating the program with the least instructions whose termination is an open question (i.e. can be linked to some open problem in mathematics). While this sort of thing would be acceptable on Code Golf, we do already have a question for this in any language, so you're probably better off (and likely to get more visibility) posting it here.

First, define a macro for used as

for (i) {
  CODE
}


that takes a variable i and any lines of CODE. It expands to

i = 0;
loop {
  CODE
  if (i == x) break;
  i++;
}


which adds $4$ instructions to CODE. If CODE

maintains the invariant $x-i$, then for runs CODE for $x+1$ times.

Next, define a function $f_n(x)$ for $n\ge0$ as

for (i_1) {
  for (i_2) {
    ...
    for (i_n) {
      x++;
      i_1++;
      i_2++;
      ...
      i_n++;
    }
    ...
  }
}


which uses $5n+1$ instructions. Observe that

incrementing both $x$ and $i_k$ maintains each invariant $x-i_k$, so each $f_n$ runs $f_{n-1}$ for $x+1$ times.

Formally, $f_n$ is defined recursively as

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x+1,&n=0\\f_{n-1}^{x+1}(x),&n\ge1\end{cases}.$$

For example,

$f_0$ increments $x$, so $f_1$ increments $x$ for $x+1$ times, giving$$f_1(x)=x+(x+1)=2x+1.$$

Finally, define the program $P_n$ as

x = 0;
x++;
x++;
f_n(x);
return x;


which uses $5n+5$ instructions and outputs $f_n(2)$.
$P_2$ uses $15$ instructions and outputs

$$f_2(2)=f_1^3(2)=f_1^2(5)=f_1(11)=23>20.$$

$P_3$ uses $20$ instructions and outputs

$$f_3(2)=f_2^3(2)=f_2^2(23)>f_2(2^{28})>2^{2^{28}}>(10^{80})^{10^6},$$which is approximately the number of atoms in the universe—to the power of one million.

$P_4$ uses $25$ instructions and outputs

$f_4(2)$, an extremely large number.

For illustration purposes, here are the three programs written in full.
$P_2$:

x = 0;
x++;
x++;
i = 0;
loop {
  j = 0;
  loop {
    x++;
    i++;
    j++;
    if (j == x) break;
    j++;
  }
  if (i == x) break;
  i++;
}
return x;


$P_3$:

x = 0;
x++;
x++;
i = 0;
loop {
  j = 0;
  loop {
    k = 0;
    loop {
      x++;
      i++;
      j++;
      k++;
      if (k == x) break;
      k++;
    }
    if (j == x) break;
    j++;
  }
  if (i == x) break;
  i++;
}
return x;


$P_4$:

x = 0;
x++;
x++;
i = 0;
loop {
  j = 0;
  loop {
    k = 0;
    loop {
      l = 0;
      loop {
        x++;
        i++;
        j++;
        k++;
        l++;
        if (l == x) break;
        l++;
      }
      if (k == x) break;
      k++;
    }
    if (j == x) break;
    j++;
  }
  if (i == x) break;
  i++;
}
return x;


Update: We can make a small optimization to $f_n$ by moving the first increment of $i_n$ after the $i_n=x$ test. This allows an extra iteration of the innermost loop, so our definition becomes

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}x+1,&n=0\\2x+2,&n=1\\f_{n-1}^{x+1}(x),&n\ge2\end{cases}.$$

Using this modified version of $f$, $P_2$ now outputs

$$f_2(2)=f_1^3(2)=f_1^2(6)=f_1(14)=30.$$

$P_3$ now outputs

$$f_3(2)=f_2^3(2)=f_2^2(30)=f_2(2^{36}-2)=2^{2^{36}+35}-2\approx100^{{10}^{10}}.$$The Googology Wiki calls this number guppythrong.

$P_4$ now outputs

$$\begin{align}f_4(2)&=f_3^3(2)\\&=f_3^2(2^{2^{36}+35}-2)\\&\approx f_3(2\uparrow\uparrow2^{2^{36}})\\&\approx2\uparrow\uparrow2\uparrow\uparrow2^{2^{36}}\\&\approx10\uparrow\uparrow10\uparrow\uparrow10\uparrow\uparrow3,\end{align}$$where $\uparrow\uparrow$ represents tetration using Knuth's up-arrow notation. The Googology Wiki calls this number trialogialogialogue.


Very nice! Can we say anything about the position of $f$ in the fast-growing hierarchy?

@BenjaminWang I think our $f_n$ is comparable to $f_n$ in the FGH for finite $n$.

Great answer! One can do better for part a.

@noedne seems about right.

@mathlander Thanks to your motivation, I found a small optimization.

Considering that the main stated puzzles have been solved, whole problem kinda transformed into free-form "busy beaver"-esk challenge/analysis...
Just to give some upper bounds on comprehensibility:
Here's a rudimentary 44-instruction program with unknown fate:
zero = 0
one = 1 // 2 instructions

count = 0
x = 7 // 8 instructions

loop
{
  count++

  temp = 0

  loop
  {
    flag_odd = 0
    if temp == x: break // detect if even
    temp++
    flag_odd++
    if temp == x: break // or odd
    temp++
  }
  // at this point temp == x

  temp2 = 0
  x = 0
  loop // even case
  {
    if flag_odd == one: break
    if temp2 == temp: break
    temp2 += 2 // 2 instructions
    x++
  }
  
  loop // odd case
  {
    if flag_odd == zero: break
    x++
    loop
    {
      if temp2 == temp: break
      temp2++
      x += 5 // 5 instructions
    }
    if zero == zero: break
  }

  if x == one: break
}
return count

it repeatedly applies "Collatz' 5n+1" function
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}n/2, &n = 2k \\ 5n+1, &n=2k+1 \end{cases}
$$
whose trajectory isn't known whether it comes down to 1 if starting value is 7 (5th term)

And here's 31-instruction program emulating anti-hydra
x = 0
big = 1
small = 0 // (big-small-1) := 0

loop
{
  temp = 0
  temp2 = 4

  small++
  loop
  {
    big += 3 // 3 instructions
    if temp == x: break // if x=2k: (big-small-1)+=2, temp2:=3k+4
    temp++; temp2++

    small += 3 // 3 instructions
    if temp == x: break // if x=2k+1: (big-small-1)-=1, temp2:=3k+5
    temp++; temp2 += 2
  }
 
  loop // x := temp2
  {
    if temp2 == x: break
    x++
  }

  if big == small: break
}
return big  // if (big-small-1) became -1: halt

it is a Collatz map
$$
\begin{cases}\text{Start} &\rightarrow (0,0)\\(2n,b) &\rightarrow (3n+4,b+2)\\ (2n+1,0) &\rightarrow \text{Halt} \\ (2n+1, b+1) &\rightarrow (3n+5, b) \end{cases}
$$
that popped up in busy beaver investigations - and it is currently unknown whether it halts or not

it hurts readability, but in anti-hydra: 1 instruction can be saved by moving single big++ to the end of the loop from the beginning (thus removing the need for small++ before the loop), 2 instructions can be saved by moving temp2 += 2 from the end of the loop to the beginning (thus saving those in temp2's initiatilization - and 2 more can be saved by switching to hydra (with $Z(a,b) = B(a+1,b)$ offset, which only changes $+4$ and $+5$ in current answer's map into $+1$ and $+3$) - for a total upper limit of 26 instructions

Code for (a):

  a = 0;
 a++;               // (repeated x5)
 b = 0;
 loop{
   a++;             // (repeated x2)
   if(a==b) break;
   b++;             // (repeated x3)
 }
 return a;

The idea is

 the loop repeatedly adds three to b, and two to a, so by the time they are equal a has been tripled.  However, having a start at 5 means we'd only get to 15.  But by putting the b++ lines after the if statement, we get two a++ lines "for free", and thus we can get to 21.


Nice solution! It looks like you can get to 25 if you change your repetitions from (x5, x2, x3) to (x1, x4, x5).

This code has exactly 15 instructions, and returns increasing powers of two, until infinity.
Here it is:
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
a++;
c++;
loop {
 loop {
  b++;
  c++;
  if (a == b) break;
 }
 loop {
  a++;
  if (a == c) break;
 }
 return c;
 b = 0;
}


I should clarify that a program stops after returning a number. (If not, it would be trivial to create a program returning every natural number.) This IS nice code, though.

This analysis is not an answer but is too long for a comment.
The bonus question asks, “What is the largest number you can return on each part?”
No matter how many instructions are allowed, I will show that the bonus question is well-defined in that there will be a unique largest positive integer $N$ that can be returned by some program.
I will analyze the 15-instruction case (the other cases are similar).
Since there are at most 15 instructions, there are at most 15 variables.  Without loss of generality, name these variables a, b, c, … m, n, o.
Let’s now consider all the possible instructions that can be used to make up a program:

It can set a variable to 0, creating it if it doesn't exist.  (15 possibilities)
It can increment a variable if the variable already exists.  (15 possibilities)
It can create a (possibly infinite) loop containing any set of instructions. Loops can be nested.  (15 possibilities:  Loop containing 0 instructions, Loop containing 1 instruction, … Loop containing 14 instructions)
It can break out of a loop if two specified variables are equal. When this type of statement is used nested loops, it only breaks the innermost loop.  (225 possibilities, 15 for first variable and 15 for second variable)
It can return a variable and stop the program.  (15 possibilities)

Some of the above possibilities are mutually exclusive or syntactically invalid but I only want to show that there are a finite number of essentially different programs.
There are at most $p=4 \times 15 + 225$ possible instructions we can use to build a program.
A program can have up to 15 instructions.  Therefore the number of essentially different possible programs is at most $E=p^0 + p^1 + p^2 + \cdots + p^{15}$.  Note although $E$ is very large, it is finite.
Even if all these $E$ programs returned an integer, there is only a finite number of possibilities for these returned values.  Call the maximum of these values $N$.  Then $N$ is the answer to the bonus question.

But is this number computable?

@Lucenaposition You found the real question :)

@Lucenaposition My analysis only shows that the bonus questions have answers.  I suspect that finding the answers or proving them optimal could be quite difficult.

It is incomputable for large n:  you can use the break condition within loops to create abritrary if-statements (branching), and since I was able to write programs for division and mods, you could use a single variable to represent a Turing tape in binary and recall arbitrary values.  That's all so say "Easy" is Turing complete, and thus if this question were computable for all N you could solve the halting problem.

And just to add, since ZF cannot prove BB(748), finding N for some specific value of N must be outside of ZF.  See this paper by Scott Aaronson.

@TylerSeacrest Alternatively, the provided instructions are exactly what's needed for general recursive functions.

Too big for a comment, but I wanted to share this explicitly:
This language is Turing-complete, proved by emulation of Fractran

Fractran program is defined as a set of fractions $\left(\frac{x_1}{y_1},\frac{x_2}{y_2},..., \frac{x_n}{y_n}\right)$ and a starting value $S_0$
On each computation step you go through fractions, one by one, first to the last - and check if $S$ is divisible by $y_i$. If it is, you calculate next value of $S$: $S_{k+1} = S_k\times \frac{x_i}{y_i}$ and move on to the next step.
Optionally, if $S$ isn't divisible by any of the denominators - machine is considered to have halted with the last value of $S$.
If you want an intuition for why Fractran is Turing-complete - look at prime factorization: $2^{f_2}3^{f_3}5^{f_5}...$ - you have infinite number of "registers" - one per each prime number - and fractions detect which of them are empty and which should be added to

To emulate Fractran in Easy, we'll need to know that:
1: we can increase variable by any constant x += c by applying x++ c times
2: we can assign variable to any constant value x = c via x=0; x += c
3: we can assign one variable to another x = y via:
x = 0
loop
{
  if x == y : break
  x++
}

4: we can define Fractran_ministep(S,x,y) to be
temp = 0; temp2 = 0; S_new = 0
loop
{
  S_new += x
  loop
  {
    temp++; temp2++      // subtract from (S-temp)
    if temp == S: break  // until it runs out
    if temp2 == y: break // or until it was decreased by y
  }
  if temp == S: break    // if it ran out, temp2 := S%y (in [1;y] range)
  temp2 = 0              // if it didn't, reset y-counter
}
if temp2 == y: break // it's the correct fraction, S_new := S*x/y

(it breaks the loop it is in with the next value of $S$ in S_new, if the fraction is correct - and continues on, if it isn't)
5: And, finally, we can construct the whole emulation program as so:
S = S_0
loop
{
  loop
  {
    x = x_1; y = y_1
    Fractran_ministep(S,x,y)

    x = x_2; y = y_2
    Fractran_ministep(S,x,y)

    ...

    x = x_n; y = y_n
    Fractran_ministep(S,x,y)

    return S
  }
  S = S_new
}

